# WPF: Не срабатывает DataTrigger из-за неправильно указанного сеттера

Tags: c#, wpf

1. Имеется изображение с заранее заданным источником
2. Данный источник через дататриггер должен меняться, основываясь на значении свойства Tag листбокса
3. Вероятность того, что свойство Tag пусто или имеет не то значение, которое нужно, отсутствует

```
<ListBox Name="someListBox"/>
<Image Source="/Folder/SubFolder/firstImage.png">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=someListBox, Path=Tag}" Value="Physical">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Folder/SubFolder/secondImage.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Однако изображение не меняется, то есть, триггер не указывает неправильный путь, а именно что не работает, в связи с чем для проверки я создал совершенно идентичный, за исключением TargetType и Property, дататриггер для текстблока, и он сработал:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=someListBox, Path=Tag}" Value="Physical">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="/Folder/SubFolder/secondImage.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

...из-за чего я определенно уверен, что проблема кроется в Property в этой строке:

```
<Setter Property="Source" Value="/Folder/SubFolder/secondImage.png"/>
```

Собственно, а в чем подвох?

Comment: В первом примере у вас пробел перед `/Folder`

Comment: @aepot Наличие пробела в этой ситуации ничего не меняет. И да, это опечатка сделана в редакторе этого сайта, в XAML пробела нет. Предположим: триггер рабочий, и я указал неправильный путь. В таком случае не проявится ни firstImage, ни secondImage, то есть, элемент Image не будет отображаться. Однако у в моем примере элемент отображается, триггер не сработал

Comment: @aepot Уже было исправлено на момент отправки второго вашего комментария

Comment: А зачем вы вяжетесь к `Tag`, что содержит `ListBox`? В курсе ли вы про `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`? Привязан ли `ListBox` к коллекции, или вы в него вручную добавляете элементы?

Comment: @aepot в данном 1) Сайт Microsoft говорит, что свойство Tag предназначено для особой информации. "Physical" вполне подходит под это определение, а на его основе я определяю, какое изображение использовать. Поэтому и привязываюсь 2) Нет, не в курсе. 3) Привязан к коллекции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так работает

```
<ListBox Name="someListBox">
            <Button Content="First" Tag="First"/>
            <Button Content="Physical" Tag="Physical"/>
        </ListBox>
        <Image>
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Folder/SubFolder/firstImage.png"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Tag, ElementName=someListBox }"
                                     Value="Physical">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="Folder/SubFolder/secondImage.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
```

Comment: Работать может и работает, но стоит такое делать или это все же костыль?)

Comment: Ну наверное больше костыль :-) я бы так не делал, но я не знаю что за контекст задачи, просто попробовал решить проблему

Comment: @ПавелПопов немного изменил свой вариант на основе вашего решения: просто перенес установку Source из непосредственно тега в сеттер. Остальное не менял. Сработало

Comment: В WPF ценятся привязки и правильная архитектура проекта, MVVM подход тоже желателен. По этой причине, `Tag` мало кто использует, а значит и такую конструкцию, что вы предоставили тоже мало кто использует. Для решения такой задачи стоит делать отдельный класс, который будет иметь в себе тот самый `Tag` как отдельное свойство и уже к нему, напрямую делать привязку, без всяких имен.

Comment: @Anton мм, я думаю ключевое изменение это Path=Tag -> Path=SelectedItem.Tag без него точно не работает т.к. в вашем случает Tag ищется в самом листе, а не строке. Хотя без переноса Source конечно то же не работает

Comment: @ПавелПопов не совсем. Я не копировал весь предложенный вами вариант в свою разметку. Единственное, что я сделал — убрал Source="..." из тега <Image> и в стиле этого элемента прописал полностью аналогичный сеттер. Именно это я взял из вашей разметки. Суть проблемы была в том, что дизайнер не позволяет менять источник изображения, если он задан в теге. Зато позволяет менять, если источник задан в стиле.
Тем не менее, ваше решение натолкнуло меня на другую идею, позволившую убрать привязку к Tag

Comment: @EvgeniyZ приму к сведению

Comment: @Anton Тут надо не принимать к сведению, а пытаться сделать так, как положено изначально. Вон вам дали ответ другой, как видите нету имен, нету тегов, лишь привязки и свойства, и вот этот вариант будет правильным в WPF проекте, задумайтесь об этом и пока не поздно, выберите правильный путь, перепишите все на привязки, ибо в этом одни плюсы, как минимум, скорость работы приложения и удобство разработки. Решать конечно вам, я даю лишь совет явному новичку в WPF.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать привязку к коллекции, и реагировать сразу на выбранный элемент коллекции.

Вот код-бихайнд

```csharp
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Items.Add("Шрек");
        Items.Add("Снеговик");
    }   
}
```

Вот разметка

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="5" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Image Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items/}" Value="Шрек">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="C:\Source\WpfApp3\WpfApp3\bin\Debug\pic1.jpg"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items/}" Value="Снеговик">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="C:\Source\WpfApp3\WpfApp3\bin\Debug\pic2.jpg"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]